# $scope becomes empty when submitting via post

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-http

I am trying to submit $scope.data using post. $scope.data goes empty when passing to a variable.

```
var token     = angular.element(document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')).attr('content');
    console.log("Questions: ");
    console.log($scope.questions);
    var qs = $scope.questions;
    $http({
      url: '/admin/exam/questions/store',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {questions: qs, _token:token}
    });
```

[image: console.log 2]

[image: console.log]

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/agYe8ocxSI7Au7J7ww62?p=preview)

Comment: what is the value of $scope.data before assigning? could you console.log and provide the result.

Comment: why don't you use $http.post("YOUR URL", DATA) ?

Comment: @TirthrajBarot what difference would that make?

Comment: Add the relevant HTML, you may have scope inheritance problem.

Comment: @Deep I have edited the code and provided a screenshot

Comment: Your screenshot shows the 'Response' tab in devtools, but that's the response from the server, what does the 'Post' tab show?

Comment: @Snixtor I added the screenshot for the post. Pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your choice of starting data type for `$scope.q`. It's being initialised as an array, like `$scope.q = [];`. You're then adding properties to that array, like in your question input control with this model binding: `ng-model="q.question"`. But when `$scope.q` is serialised to JSON, those extra properties are ignored.

Instead of initialising `q` as an Array, initialise it as an Object, like: `$scope.q = {}`.

You can diagnose the JSON representation of the `q` object by adding the following expression in your view: `{{q | json}}`.

Comment: awesome!! Thanks!!

I had to change some of the array methods but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one case when it is possible. When you are setting 
 var qs = $scope.data; $scope.data is empty. And you get link to the empty variable.  So first point is to use post like this

```
var qs = $scope.data;
$http({
  url: '/admin/exam/questions/store',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {questions: **$scope.data**, _token:token}
});
```

Second point is debug :) But i think my first approach will help

Comment: I still got nothing. I'm pretty much stuck.

Comment: Cood you provide plunker? 
And what this code will log?
var qs = $scope.data;
console.log('qs: ', qs);

$http({
  url: '/admin/exam/questions/store',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {questions: **$scope.data**, _token:token}
});